# How to use an iterator to find a specific title in an object that is part of an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to use an iterator to find a specific object in my array-list and then add fields to the specific object. I have the fields title and format already added to my object but I need to then add a name and date to a specific object. My class with getters and setters is called MediaItem. The way I currently have it is that the name and date fields are being added into every object. Any help understanding how to make it so that my code is only added to a specific object would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Library {

static ArrayList<MediaItem> items = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();





static void addNewItem(String title, String format) {
        MediaItem b = new MediaItem();
        b.setTitle(title);
        b.setFormat(format);
        items.add(b);
}

static void markItemOnLoan(String title, String name, String date) {
        Iterator<MediaItem> it = items.iterator();
        for (MediaItem mi : items){
            it.next();
            it.equals(title);
            mi.setLoanedTo(name);
            mi.setDateLoaned(date);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: You're currently calling `equals` but not doing anything with the result - and you don't want to compare the *iterator* with the item anyway. You probably don't want the iterator at all - just use the for loop and check whether or not it's the right one with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating through the Arraylist you can either make use of the for-each loop or iterate using Iterators. You are trying to use both of them together and I dont see any advantage in that. You want to do something like this :

Option 1 :

```
  Iterator<MediaItem> it = items.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
     MediaItem mi = it.next();
     if(mi.getTitle().equals(title))
     {
       mi.setLoanedTo(name);
       mi.setDateLoaned(date);
     }

  }
```

Option 2 :

```
  for(MediaItem mi : items)
  {
      if(mi.getTitle().equals(title))
     {
       mi.setLoanedTo(name);
       mi.setDateLoaned(date);
     }
  }
```

The advantage of Option 1 over Option 2 is that if say in future you decide to modify the arraylist as you are iterating through it (eg: delete MediaItem object when the title matches) then you wont be able to do that in Option 2 (for-each). On the other hand Option 2 is very compact and less verbose as compared to Option 1

Comment: Thank you! I do need to modify the arraylist in the future and option one works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Iterator if you use that kind of for loop.
Also, it.equals should be an "if" statement, and it should compare with a specific field.

```
static void markItemOnLoan(String title, String name, String date) {
    for (MediaItem mi : items){
        if(mi.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            mi.setLoanedTo(name);
            mi.setDateLoaned(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do

```
while (it.hasNext())
```

instead of

```
for (MediaItem mi: items)
```

If you note the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), you'll see that you can use `hasNext()` to check if there are any items in the `Collection` after the one to which the `Iterator` currently points.

Then, use the fact that `next()` returns the element to do your comparison, and be sure to actually perform a comparison by using an `if` block.

```
MediaItem mi = it.next();
if (mi.equals(title)) {
    // do whatever
}
```